# Form action is working with Chrome but not working with Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, backbone.js

I am using Backbone js. I want to call a PHP page and have to show in iframe on form submit. I have used underscore.js for templating.
My html template is,

```
    <div class="tag-popup-field confirmPopup">
    <form action="discover.php?perform=addnewdevice" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="" id="submitDiscoverData" name="submitData">
        <div class="btnContainer">
            <input type="submit" class="simpleBtn" id="submitDataform" value="Discover">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="iframeContainer">
    <iframe name="iframe_addDevice" id="iframe_addDevice" class="upgradeCollectorIframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

The view where i call above template is,

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/DiscoverConfirmation.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, DiscoverConfirmation) {
  view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
    },
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'tag-popup',
    render: function (obj, action, msg, name) {
      console.log('success');
      $(this.el).html(_.template(DiscoverConfirmation, {}));
      return this.el;
    }
  });
  return view;
});
```

After clicking on '#submitDataform' i need to submit the form data to php page and show the page in iframe.
Its working fine with chrome but not working in firefox.

In firefox form action is not working.

Comment: _“'src' attribute of iframe is not getting set on submitting the form in firefox”_ – it is not supposed to … sending something into an iframe via `target` attribute will not change the `src` attribute in HTML.

Comment: "not working in firefox" - that's a very vague description of the problem. What actually happens in Firefox?

Comment: POST action of a form is not getting performed in firefox. so that the targeted page is not visible in iframe.

Comment: this doesn't seem like simple html problem, please tag correctly if you want people to help you